# Getting error when trying to do vlookup with pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, count, mapping, vlookup

So here is what I am trying to do.
I have a large data frame named newdf. It has several rows, but the relevant ones for this are year, and product name. I need to count the number of times the same product names appear in each year (from 2018 to 2021), and create a new dataframe that would look like below.

| Product Name | 2018 | 2019 | 20120 | 20121 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 0 | 5 | 10 | 8 |
| xyz | 2 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

---

Here is what I have done so far

```
df_target = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name': newdf['Product Name']}) #copied only the product name column to new dataframe df_target

df_target.drop_duplicates(subset= 'Product Name', keep='first') # deleted duplicates from this dataframe.

    df_target["2018"]=""
    df_target["2019"]=""   #adding empty columns to the dataframe where results can later be added
    df_target["2020"]=""
    df_target["2021"]=""


    df_target.set_index("Product Name",inplace = True) #Setting Product Name as index

    df_2018 = newdf.query('YEAR == "2018"')
    df_2019 = newdf.query('YEAR == "2019"')
    df_2020 = newdf.query('YEAR == "2020"') #creating new dataframes for each year by filtering the original one
    df_2021 = newdf.query('YEAR == "2021"')
  

    counts_2018 = pd.DataFrame(df_2018.Product Name.value_counts().reset_index())
    counts_2019 = pd.DataFrame(df_2019.Product Name.value_counts().reset_index())
    counts_2020 = pd.DataFrame(df_2020.Product Name.value_counts().reset_index())
    counts_2021 = pd.DataFrame(df_2021.Product Name.value_counts().reset_index())  # Counting the number of times a product number appears in each year


    counts_2018.columns = ['Product Name', ' 2018']
    counts_2019.columns = ['Product Name', ' 2019']
    counts_2020.columns = ['Product Name', ' 2020']
    counts_2021.columns = ['Product Name', ' 2021'] # Labelling the columns in the count dataframes.


    df_target["2018"] = df_target.index.map(counts_2018["2018"])  # This last line of code is where I get the error. When I try to map data from the count data frame to the target one that I created earlier. The error is below
```

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)2392             try:-> 2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)2394             except KeyError:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas_libs\index.c:5239)()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas_libs\index.c:5085)()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas_libs\hashtable.c:20405)()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas_libs\hashtable.c:20359)()
>
> KeyError: '2018'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-18-cf92c30b79a3> in <module>()
> ----> 1 df_target["2018"] = df_target.index.map(counts_2018["2018"])
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in **getitem**(self, key)
> 2060             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> 2061         else:
> -> 2062             return self._getitem_column(key)
> 2063
> 2064     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
> 2067         # get column
> 2068         if self.columns.is_unique:
> -> 2069             return self._get_item_cache(key)
> 2070
> 2071         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
> 1532         res = cache.get(item)
> 1533         if res is None:
> -> 1534             values = self._data.get(item)
> 1535             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
> 1536             cache[item] = res
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
> 3588
> 3589             if not isnull(item):
> -> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
> 3591             else:
> 3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
> 2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
> 2394             except KeyError:
> -> 2395                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
> 2396
> 2397         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas_libs\index.c:5239)()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas_libs\index.c:5085)()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas_libs\hashtable.c:20405)()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas_libs\hashtable.c:20359)()
>
> KeyError: '2018'

---

The error is big, and I cant find a way to resolve it. Can anyone please advice?

Comment: `counts_2018.columns = ['Product Name', ' 2018']`. You have a leading space before 2018.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I get a different error though. I get a TypeError. It says series object is not callable. But shouldnt all the objects be in a pandas dataframe as per the code?